# Brand new to angular. Making a very simple test app. Can't figure something out

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been learning web development for about 5 months now, and this is my first time trying out angular. When I watched a tutorial for using ng-model and {{curly-brace expressions}} to bind data, I wanted to try it out to make a simple Google Font pairing app. You enter the text for the header, and for the body, and then you can choose different fonts from drop down menus for each to test various font pairings. Simple idea. And it works. But the one problem I'm having is making the names of the fonts in the drop-down menus written in that font. Here's what I have so far (and sorry, the CSS I'm including is just a bunch of @imports for fonts so it would work in the test environment. Kind of ugly):

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('FontTester', function($scope){
  $scope.fonts=["Open Sans", "Roboto", "Roboto Condensed", "Lato", "Oswald","Lora","Source Sans Pro", "PT Sans", "Open Sans Condensed", "Droid Sans", "Raleway", "Montserrat", "Ubuntu", "Droid Serif", "Roboto Slab", "Merriweather", "Arimo", "PT Sans Narrow", "Noto Sans", "Bitter", "Titillium Web", "Lobster", "PT Serif", "Oxygen", "Dosis", "Hind", "Cabin", "Arvo", "Fjalla One", "Playfair Display", "Vollkorn", "Abel", "Bree Serif", "Muli", "Poiret One", "Francois One", "Noto Serif", "Nunito", "Signika", "Play", "Inconsolata", "Ubuntu Condensed", "Archivo Narrow", "Anton", "Cuprum", "Alegreya", "Pacifico", "Karla", "Libre Baskerville", "Josephin Sans", "Asap", "Maven Pro", "Rokkitt", "Merriweather Sans", "Monda", "Dancing Script", "Quicksand", "Exo", "Varela Round", "PT Sans Caption", "Crimson Text", "Crete Round", "Questrial", "Pathway Gothic One", "Fira Sans", "Ropa Sans", "Abril Fatface", "Armata", "Patua One", "News Cycle", "Pontano Sans", "Istok Web", "Gudea", "Josephin Slab", "Noticia Text", "EB Garamond", "Cabin Condensed", "Jura", "Sanchez", "Lobster Two", "BenchNine", "Quattrocento Sans", "Old Standard TT", "Courgette", "Ruda", "Playball", "Alfa Slab One", "Righteous", "Kreon", "Passion One"].sort();
})
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monterrat);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Francois+One);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josephin+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monda);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Caption);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crete+Round);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pathway+Gothic+One);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ropa+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Armata);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pontano+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Istok+Web);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gudea);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josephin+Slab);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noticia+Text);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Condensed);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sanchez);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Benchnine);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Old+Standard+TT);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ruda);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kreon);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One);




body {
  background: #bbb;
}
input {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  font-family: mono;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
select {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  font-family: mono;
}
textarea {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: mono;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
}
p {
  font-size: 18px;
  Margin: 0;
}
.inputs {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
.inputs>p {
  width: 200px;
}
.sampleText {
  background: white;
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sampleText>h1, .sampleText>p {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">         </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="FontTester">
    <h1></h1>
    <div class="inputs">
      <div class="header">
        <p>Select Header Font:</p>
        <select ng-model="headerFont">
          <option ng-repeat="font in fonts" value="{{font}}">{{font}}</option>
        </select>
        <p>Set Header Text:</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="header">
      </div>
      <div class="bodytext">
        <p>Select Body Font:</p>
        <select ng-model="bodyFont">
          <option ng-repeat="font in fonts" value="{{font}}">{{font}}</option>
        </select>
        <p>Set Body Text:</p>
        <textarea rows="8" cols="19" ng-model="bodytext"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sampleText" style="background:{{bgcolor}};">
      <h1 style="font-family: '{{headerFont}}';">{{header}}</h1>
      <p style="font-family: '{{bodyFont}}';">{{bodytext}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried wrapping the {{font}} that's in the ng-repeated options inside of , but that didn't work. With my extremely limited knowledge of data-binding, I can't really think of any other way to do it, and it's bothering me. Anyone know why that didn't work, and what I can do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This should work using ng-style (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

```
<select ng-model="bodyFont">
      <option ng-repeat="font in fonts" value="{{font}}" ng-style="{'font-family':font}>{{font}}</option>
 </select>
```